# Python - Replace negative infinity values within a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As written in the title, I need to replace `-inf` values within a pandas data frame. I would like to replace them by nan-values. There are multiple columns containing `-inf` so it should be run over the whole data frame.

I tried `df.replace(np.inf, np.nan)` which only seems to work with positive infinity. Also tried `df.replace('-inf', np.nan)`.

How do I replace negative infinity values in my dataframe?

Comment: `df.replace(-np.inf, np.nan)`?

Comment: `df.replace(np.NINF, np.nan)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below, rather than `'inf'` as a string:

```
df.replace(-np.Inf, np.nan)
```